# What is the difference between using the object prototype and not using the object prototype in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I `console.log` the code I get same result. What is difference between `potential.prototype.constructor` and `potential`. And how we can use it?

```
function potential(Action, Romantic, Drama, Comedy){
    this.Action = "Action";
    this.Romantic = "Romantic";
    this.Drama = "Drama";
    this.Comedy = "Comedy";
}

console.log(potential.prototype.constructor);
console.log(potential);
```

Comment: this headline is not very useful....but anyway - what does your console print? ;)

Comment: It prints,  function potential(Action, Romantic, Drama, comedy){
 this.Action = "Action";
 this.Romantic = "Romantic";
 this.Drama = "Drama";
 this.comedy = "Comedy";
}

Comment: there is none difference. prototype is a special fields that will hold the method of your class, constructor is a reference to the constructor of the class, which is the function itself as it was declared. Since you can do `new potential(..)`. Furthermore you can add method to your class by adding function to the prototype. For more information : if you don't know POO you should read the basics online and then only read how you can use it in javascript

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion. :) @Walfrat.